# Visual Studio режим "только для чтения"

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio-2017

Почему скрипт стает "только для чтения" в Visual Studio C# после нажатия "Подключить к Unity" . Как я могу его потом редактировать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Подключить к юнити" переводит скрипт в режим выполнения. Во время работы скрипты редактировать нельзя. Чтоб восстановить возможность редактирования, работу скрипта надо остановить (нажать красный прямоугольник). Для того чтобы увидеть изменения в самом юнити, сцену тоже надо перезапустить.